# Proof involving the function $T(f)$ = $\int_\limits{0}^{1}(1+x^2)f(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, supremum-and-infimum

Let f : [0, 1] → $\mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then we can define the function $T : C[0, 1]$ → $\mathbb{R}$ by:

$T(f)$ = $\int_\limits{0}^{1}(1+x^2)f(x)dx$ (since the product of continuous functions is continuous).

Show that there exists a constant K with the property that for all $f\in C[0, 1]$,
$|T(f)|$ ≤ $K||f||_\infty$ $\leftarrow$ (refers to sup norm).

Use the result to prove that if {$f_n$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in C[0, 1] such that
$f_n$ → f in the sup norm, then the sequence of numbers $T(f_n)$ converges to the
number $T(f)$.

I am not really sure how to go about starting this problem.

Comment: More generally, for any continuous $k:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, if $T(f)=\int_a^b\,f(x)\,k(x)\,\text{d}x$ for each $f\in \mathcal{C}[a,b]$, then the operator norm $\|T\|$ of $T$ with respect to the supremum norm $\|\_\|_\infty$ on $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ is $\|k\|_1=\int_a^b\,\big|k(x)\big|\,\text{d}x$.  (Well, $k$ does not need to be continuous, even.  It just has to be Lebesgue-integrable on $[a,b]$.  Also, $\mathcal{C}[a,b]$ can be replaced by the space $\mathcal{L}^\infty[a,b]$ of essentially bounded functions on $[a,b]$, and $[a,b]$ can be replaced by a Lebesgue-measurable $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Notice that $|\int_0^1 g(x) dx | \le \int_0^1 |g(x)| dx$ holds for any integrable $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ and the integral is monoton, that is $g \le h$ implies $\int g \le \int h$.

Comment: @user251257 How could I use this to show that the sequence of numbers $T(f_n)$ converges to the number $T(f)$? What you said was one of the suggested theorems to use for the problem, so using your comment would be on the right track.

Comment: $T(f_n) - T(f) = T(f_n - f)$...

Answer (score 3):

$$|T(f)|=|\int_0^1(1+x^2)f(x)dx|$$

$$\leq ||f||_\infty \int_0^1(1+x^2)dx$$

and you take $K=\int_0^1(1+x^2)dx=\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: I am really confused how to use this K to form the following proof.

Comment: @JohnH is it ok now

Comment: Sorry, I am just having trouble trying to understand what I am supposed to prove. So from here, we have |T(f)| $\leq$ $||f||_{\infty}$$4\over{3}$